# Instantiating a deep object and referencing different levels in other instances

Tags: vue.js

I would like to know how to render two html elements that reference different levels in the same object.

Let's say I have a global deep object:

```
var sports = [{
   sportName: 'soccer',
   teams: [{
     teamName: 'TeamA'
     },
     {
     teamName: 'TeamB'
     }  
   ]
 },
 {
   sportName: 'basketball',
   teams: [{
     teamName: 'TeamC'
     },
     {
     teamName: 'TeamD'
     }  
   ]
 }
```

]

Now, I want to two unordered lists that represent the different levels in the hierarchy of that object.

```
<ul id="sports">
  <li v-for:"sport in sports">
    <span>{{ sport.sportName }}</span>
  </li>
</ul> 

<script>
  var sportsList = new Vue({
    el:'#sports',
    data: {
      sports: sports
    }
  })
</script>
```

Here is the other list, in a completely different part of the app:

```
<ul id="teams">
  <li v-for:"team in teams">
    <span>{{ team.teamName }}</span>
  </li>
</ul> 

<script>
  var sportsList = new Vue({
    el:'#teams',
    data: {
      teams: sports[sportName].teams
    }
  })
</script>
```

My questions are these:

1) Will rendering two seperate instances of the different levels in the  `sports` data object still result in data reactivity in each of those instances?

2) I've noticed that as soon as I instantiate the first list (sports), the `get` and `set` for the nested items (`teams`) are stored in the prototype... which leads me on to the next question. Does it make sense to instantiate a second Vue instance for `teams`, when it has already been instantiated in the first? I'm finding it difficult to navigate deeper objects within Vue :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach is to use a computed, rather than trying to copy parts of an array to data, which can cause you to end up in a bit of a mess. So in your case I can see you're trying to get teams for a sport, so I would set up a computed that returns teams for a sport stored in data:

```
  computed: {
    teams() {
      return this.sports.filter(sport => {
        return this.sportName === sport.sportName
      })[0].teams;
    }
  },
```

Now all you need to do is set a data property called `sportName` which that filter can react to, so the full view model looks like this:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    teams() {
      return this.sports.filter(sport => {
        return this.sportName === sport.sportName
      })[0].teams;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setSport(name) {
      this.sportName = name;
    }
  },
  data: {
    sportName: 'basketball',
    sports: [{
      sportName: 'soccer',
      teams: [{
        teamName: 'TeamA'
      }, {
        teamName: 'TeamB'
      }]
    }, {
      sportName: 'basketball',
      teams: [{
        teamName: 'TeamC'
      }, {
        teamName: 'TeamD'
      }]
    }]
  }
});
```

And here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hgw2upzf/

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. So, you're only instantiating one  app? What if there is a large amount of other HTML elements that are separating the two lists? Can there be other Vue elements within that the broader `app` instance/element?

Comment: Dumb question, but, is  `teams()` the same as `teams: function()`, and is acceptable use in the instance object?

Comment: @Modermo Yes, that's ES2015 syntax so you will need to use a transpiler (such as [babel](https://babeljs.io)) to use it in the browser, otherwise you can stick with the ES5 syntax you are using. In answer to you other question, you can use [single page components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) to gradually build your app. If you are not familiar with all the build tools you can use [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) to quickly scaffold your app, and as always if you run in to trouble you can always ask for help here.